# Не получается передать переменную в другую функцию

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot

Пытаюсь передать переменную `sqlid` из categories_edit в функцию `new_category`, но при попытке поместить `sqlid[0]` в таблицу, вылезает ошибка:

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'
```

```
def categories_edit(message):
    global sqlid
    sqlid = c.execute("SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name=?", (message.text,)).fetchone()
    categories_keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    categories_keyboard.row('Создать категорию')
    if message.text == 'Создать категорию':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите имя новой категории')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, new_category)
    allcnames = c.execute("SELECT name FROM categories").fetchall()
    print(allcnames)
    for i in allcnames:
        cleari = str(i[0])
        if message.text == cleari:
            print(sqlid)
            allroot = c.execute("SELECT name FROM categories WHERE root=?", (sqlid[0],)).fetchall()
            print(allroot)
            print('this is allroot')
            for i in allroot:
                categories_keyboard.row(str(i[0]))
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ok', reply_markup=categories_keyboard)
            print(message)
            del categories_keyboard
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, categories_edit)
def new_category(message):
    global sqlid
    with lock:
        count = c.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories').fetchone()
        print(count[0])
        print(sqlid)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'wwakwwkawk')
        c.execute(f"INSERT INTO payment_balance VALUES(?,?,?)", (message.text, count, sqlid[0]))
```

Comment: В вашем коде нет даже элементарно отступов, поэтому понять ничего нельзя. Я пытался его исправить, но что часть функций, а что нет, не понял.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rG1zq8Cs вот, так лучше

Comment: Ну вот, теперь я вам вопрос исправил: нормально выглядит, а то так ничего не понято было, заминусовали бы.

Comment: а что вам выводит строка `print(sqlid)` в функции `categories_edit`?

Comment: То, что отправил пользователь в ЛС телеграмм-боту, другими словами, всё что угодно.

Comment: @xlezs а тип данных у этой переменной какой ? `type(sqlid)`

Comment: type(sqlid) = tuple, type(sqlid[0]) = int.

Comment: Это значит, что sqlid не массив (коллекция). Попробуйте вывести его на экран